# Tableau MS_Access Not Returning Correct Count

Tags: ms-access, tableau-api

I have connected Tableau to an MS-Access backend as my datasource.

One of my tables has testing categories (1-19) and the other table has the actual tests done by different supervisors. Each test that the supervisor completes is assigned a category.   I need to show a count of how many tests in each category each supervisor has completed in a given month.

I am able to show the count if the supervisor completed a test in a category, the problem I am having is when the supervisor has not completed any test, tableau is not showing the category at all.  I need tableau to show the category and a count of 0.

It is showing some categories with a zero count, I believe this is because this supervisor has completed a test in this category during a previous month.

I have tried all different type of join with no luck.
I do not believe that access allows a full outer join.

Screenshot for one supervisor for the month of April (not all categories are showing).

[image]

**Desired results**-Screenshot for one supervisor for the month of April (with all categories showing).

[image]

Here is my datasource
[image]

SPARTN_Livefeed contains the test information.  Supervisor that completed the test, the test number they did and the date.

R_TestCatalog contains a list of all the test numbers and the category id each test belongs to.

R_TestCategory contains all the categories and the test numbers that belong to each category.

sample data

```
SPARTN_Livefeed
Sheet_ID  Supervisor_ID   Test Number   Date
OB-111       1111            101          01/01/2020
OB-112       1111            401          03/01/2020
OB-113       1111            201          01/01/2020
OB-114       2222            201          01/01/2020
OB-115       2222            201          01/21/2020


R_TestCatalog
test number        category id
101                    1
201                    2
301                    2
401                    8


R_TestCategory
category id       category description
--------------------------------------
1                 Signals
2                 Restricted Speed
3                 Equip Securement
etc, etc ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a table of all possible combinations of Category and Supervisor. You should be able to create this with a cross join in access. Then left join that cross-joined table (or query) to your test date. That will give a record for all categories and supervisors, even when there hasn't been a test.

Comment: I have tried something similar but unable to get results.  I updated my original question, please see above

Comment: Look at the joins. At no point are you left joining SPARTN_Livefeed to a list of all supervisors and R_testcatalogs. Your first step should be to create the cross join of all tests and supervisor combinations then left join SPARTN_Livefeed to the output of the cross join.

Comment: when I try to do a left join on the supervisor with SPARTN_LiveFeed I get database error - Join Expression Not Supported

Comment: It could be a syntax thing, I don't know. Access may only support LEFT OUTER JOIN. If necessary build out the entire thing as an Access query and connect Tableau to that query

Comment: `SELECT Categories.ID, Supervisors.ID FROM Categories, Supervisors;` will generate a dataset of all possible category/supervisor pairs. This is a Cartesian product query. Now build aggregate query object with filter query if needed and use both queries in another query with compound join on ID fields.

Comment: But of course use your actual fields in place of my generic examples. @AndyTARSols has essentially the right idea but could expand on answer with additional guidance as outlined in my comment.

Comment: I have done that but access will not allow that type of join.  Access will only return categories if a test was complete.  I need it to show all categories and a count of 0 if no tests were completed

Comment: Cross joins are possible in Access.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6#bmcross. You need to cross join the table with all categories and the table with all supervisors. Then left join what actually hapened to the result of the cross join.

Comment: Still not working.
FROM reporting_tomt_2_targets, reporting_tomt_1_spartn
WHERE Month(reporting_tomt_2_targets.to_startdate ) <= [forms]![testform]![txt_hiddenmonth]  
AND reporting_tomt_2_targets.testofficersapid =   reporting_tomt_1_spartn.[supervisor id]
AND reporting_tomt_2_targets.categoryid=reporting_tomt_1_spartn.testcategoryid

Comment: Not sure what join you're attempting there but it's not a cross join. You're specifying where Table1.Field=Table2.Field, which creates an inner join.